# How do I generate 5 random problems?

Tags: java

I am having trouble writing the correct code for generating 5 random math problems and being able to enter in a answer and being either told it is correct or wrong. this is what I have so far

```
public static void addNumOneToTen(Scanner keyboard)
{
    int startValue = 1, endValue = 10;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the answer to the problem:");
       int ranNumberOne = (int)(startValue + Math.random() * (endValue - startValue + 1));
       int ranNumberTwo = (int)(startValue + Math.random() * (endValue - startValue + 1));

       while (ranNumberOne < ranNumberTwo)
       {
       ranNumberOne = (int)(startValue + Math.random() * (endValue - startValue +1));
       ranNumberTwo = (int)(startValue + Math.random() * (endValue - startValue +1));
       }
    }
}
```

And when i hit run i generate this

Please choose one of the following options for your math quiz:
1. Addition with numbers 1-10
2. Addition with numbers 1-100
3. Subtraction with numbers 1-10
4. Subtraction with numbers 1-100
5. Multiplication with numbers 1-10
6. Exit the program

1
Enter the answer to the problem:
Enter the answer to the problem:
Enter the answer to the problem:
Enter the answer to the problem:
Enter the answer to the problem:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)

I do not know what I have done wrong. I had thought I had it right. Could anyone help at all?

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the value from scanner within the loop which you are not doing. So something like:

```
 double nextNumber = keyboard.nextDouble();//or nextInt for next integer.
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29

Comment: Your current code just runs the loop 5 times without ever receiving input.

Comment: yea so OP needs to fetch the value from system input which OP can get by calling keyboard.nextDouble within the loop to accept the input.